# linux usb virtual printer as a usb printer on windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, embedded-linux

i want to create a "linux box" with 2 usb.
first usb is attacched to windows pc
the second to printer on linux.

Now the first usb (windows-to-linux usb device), must be seen by windows as a printer
is it possible?
for the second isn't a problem have resolved with cups

how can i do?

Comment: Doing this literally would require atypical hardware more common in embedded systems.  But why must the connection be USB?  Why not emulate a network printer?

Comment: @TheNeXt I have the exact same need now.. have you found any solution / device to this since then?

Answer (score 0):

You need the [gadget printer module](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/gadget_printer.txt) and hardware that supports USB on the go or slave.

The point for hardware is that USB has one master (the PC) and several slaves (the devices). With Linux, you can make a PC or an embedded system behave like a device (with the gadget modules), but you also need support in hardware, so that it appears as a slave. USB On The Go (OTG) is a type of port that can be programmed (or even it can auto-detect) to be master or slave, but is ofter available in embedded systems, and I've never seen in on PCs.